# Dojo Make label clickable

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have the following code as part of dojo javascript file:
    `<div id="lblOne"><label onClick="callMyFunction()">Compose</label></div>`
But now when I click the label I get an error: "callMyFunction is undefined". 
I have also tried using:
    `dojo.query("#lblOne").onclick(function() {alert('Function Called!');});` But this also not working. Anything am missing?

Comment: I'd suggest updating your question post and include more of your sample.  Specifically, where is the global function called "callMyFunction" defined?

Comment: The code is a lot and for other reasons cannot show more code. Still I don't think this stops someone from being able to provide a solution. Using dojo.query may require more code but making a label clickable doesn't which is basically what I want. Thanks.

Comment: If what you've posted is, indeed, a copy-paste, it seems you're missing an end-quote after "callMyFunction(). Malformed HTML can tend to cause all sorts of issues without noticably breaking the page.

Comment: That was a typo and fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be found at the JSFiddle link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kolban/nfhP7/

In summary, it consists of the following HTML:

```
<label id="myId">Hello World</label>
```

and the following JavaScript:

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/on"], function(
    dom, on) {
    var node = dom.byId("myId");
    on(node, "click", function() {
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code works on jsfiddle so I will accept it even though it's not working for me. I think it may be scope problem or such, thus I will look for other solutions.